# Why can't I store my object in a variable within a Parallel ForEach-Object loop?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-7.0

I'm trying to retrieve the AD property `LastLogon` from each of our domain controllers, for each user. Due to the amount of time this will take, I'm trying to use the `Parallel` feature from PowerShell 7

## Example

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter "[filter]"
$DCs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Where-Object { $_.Site -in $using:sites }

$users | ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit 2  -Parallel {    
    $serv = $using:DCs

    foreach ($DC in $serv) {
        $lastLogonAD = Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Properties LastLogon -Server $DC -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastLogon

        $lastLogonConverted = [datetime]::FromFileTimeUTC($lastLogonAD)
    }
}
```

#### Error

```
Get-ADUser: 
Line |
   7 |  …        $lastLogonAD = Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Properties LastLogon -Server  …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration context.
```

What I've found is that if I remove the `-Server` parameter, it works, or if I don't store the property into a variable, it works.

###### Removing the server parameter

```
    foreach ($DC in $DCs) {
        $lastLogonAD = Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Properties LastLogon -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastLogon

        $lastLogonConverted = [datetime]::FromFileTimeUTC($lastLogonAD)
    }
```

##### Not storing the variable

```
    foreach ($DC in $DCs) {
        Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Properties LastLogon -Server $DC -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastLogon

        $lastLogonConverted = [datetime]::FromFileTimeUTC($lastLogonAD)
    }
```

Comment: The "The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration context." is mainly because your code is very inefficient. As for "if I remove the `-Server` parameter, it works", well yes, this depends on distance and your DCs hardware and network.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I made a mistake in my last example, please check it again as using the `Server` parameter there it works fine. And I don't understand how it can be more efficient? There's only 1 real call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration context." is mainly because your code is very inefficient, this error occurs on queries running for more than 30 minutes. See TechNet article [Active Directory Troubleshooting: server has returned the following error - invalid enumeration context](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32418.active-directory-troubleshooting-server-has-returned-the-following-error-invalid-enumeration-context.aspx).

Your parallel loop should be running **per Domain Controller** instead of **per User**. The parallel invocations should be processing all users per runspace.

What below code does:

1. Get a list of `DistinguishedName`s that will be processed in parallel.
2. Start parallel invocations per Domain Controller and pass that list of `DistinguishedName`s to process per parallel invocation.
3. Then group all results by `DistinguishedName`, sort each group by `LastLogon` and pick user on each group with the latest `LastLogon`.
4. Lastly, project the object with a constructed "friendly" property `LastLogonDate`.

```bash
$sites = # needs to be defined here...

# only need the users `DistinguishedName` here
$users = (Get-ADUser -Filter '[filter]').DistinguishedName

# parallel loop per DC instead of per user
Get-ADDomainController -Filter * |
    Where-Object { $_.Site -in $sites } |
    ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        $using:users | Get-ADUser -Properties LastLogon -Server $_
    } |
    Group-Object DistinguishedName |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group | Sort-Object LastLogon -Descending -Top 1 |
            Select-Object *, @{ N='LastLogonDate'; E={ [datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc($_.LastLogon) }}
    }
```

If you really need to have a reference of the Source DC per user then the way around it is to recreate the objects with a new `SourceDC` property inside the parallel loop, for instance:

```
    # No code changes before this
    ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        $sourceDC = $_
        $using:users | Get-ADUser -Properties LastLogon -Server $_ |
            Select-Object *, @{ N='SourceDC'; E={ $sourceDC.Name }}
    }
    # No code changes after this
```

If you're still facing the same issue after this change then you will need to reduce the number of users you're querying. Or perhaps you can try with a single call to the DCs using an elaborate LDAP Filter:

```
# create one big ldap filter
$filter = -join @(
    '(|'
    (Get-ADUser -Filter '[filter]').DistinguishedName |
        ForEach-Object { "(distinguishedName=$_)" }
    ')'
)

Get-ADDomainController -Filter * |
    Where-Object { $_.Site -in $sites } |
    ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        # then using this filter we can make a single call per DC
        Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $using:filter -Properties LastLogon -Server $_
    } |
    # rest of the code stays the same here...
```

Comment: wow I think this will work.. just one question, how can I include the server name with the most recent lastLogon property?

Comment: Sorry I have a second question - you're using lots of `ForEach-Object`s and pipes here, isn't it more efficient to store these and use `foreach`?

Comment: @swtto see the update reg. the source server. as for `foreach` vs `ForEach-Object` it depends. The last `ForEach-Object` could be replaced by `foreach` if you don't mind having all output in memory. Up to you and your hardware and how many results you will end up having. The current code allows you to add a next pipeline to `Export-Csv` for example so the memory usage should be low.

Comment: Awesome, I think small error in the `SourceDC` expression, should be `$sourceDC.Name`

Comment: @swtto oh you're right! sorry. fixed it thanks