# Poweshell script to disable user accounts that have not logged in for over 90 days and moves them to the Disabled Users OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I work for an MSP, and I have been working on a script that helps clean up AD for our customers. Many of our customers do not tell us when employees leave, so this will keep AD tidy and eliminate security holes. The script I have come up with does not seem to find all the users it should, and I've confirmed there are indeed active users on our AD that do not work here anymore. Any tips would be greatly appreciated. This version is to test, where it just prints the users it finds into a text file.

```
# Set the time threshold (in days) for inactive user accounts
$inactiveDays = 90

# Get the domain name from the environment variable
$domain = $env:USERDOMAIN

# Set the distinguished name (DN) of the Disabled Users OU
$disabledUsersOU = "OU=DisabledUsers,DC=$domain"  # Update this with actual OU path

# Get the current date and calculate the threshold date for inactive accounts
$thresholdDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$inactiveDays)

# Get inactive users based on the last logon date, excluding users in the Administrators group
$inactiveUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter {
    LastLogonDate -lt $thresholdDate -and
    Enabled -eq $true -and
    MemberOf -notlike "*CN=Administrators,*"
} -Properties LastLogonDate

# Path to text file
$filePath = "C:\testCleanup\inactives.txt"

# Check if the folder exists, create it if not
if (-not (Test-Path "C:\testCleanup" -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\testCleanup"
}

# Prints DistinguishedName to file
foreach ($user in $inactiveUsers) {
    $user.DistinguishedName | Out-File -FilePath $filePath -Append
}

# Display a message indicating that the operation is complete
Write-Host "DistinguishedNames of inactive users (excluding Administrators) printed to $filePath"
```

Comment: `MemberOf -notlike "*CN=Administrators,*"` is not valid in your filter. You can't apply wildcards on an attribute that has distinguished names.

Comment: Powershell lets me, and that's not why it's not working. I commented that part out, and still misses many users. Any other ideas?

Comment: even if the AD module allows you to use that filter, it will not filter anything, the LDAP translation is simply invalid. as for lastLogonDate there is a 14 day time diff for this attribute, you need to query all your DC targeting the lastLogon attribute as explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75339028/15339544

Comment: It's still an invalid point, because even without that line, it still doesn't do anything. So bringing it up simply does not contribute to the discussion.

Comment: Of course it does because you have a misconception about how the LDAP Filter used behind the scenes works... As for the missing users I have already explained in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **`LastLogonTimestamp`**

Heres an updated script:

```
$inactiveDays = 90
$domain = $env:USERDOMAIN
$disabledUsersOU = "OU=DisabledUsers,DC=$domain"
$thresholdDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$inactiveDays)
$inactiveUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter { LastLogonTimestamp -lt $thresholdDate -and Enabled -eq $true } -Properties LastLogonTimestamp
$filePath = "C:\testCleanup\inactives.txt"
if (-not (Test-Path "C:\testCleanup" -PathType Container)) {
   New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\testCleanup"
}
foreach ($user in $inactiveUsers) {
   $user.DistinguishedName | Out-File -FilePath $filePath -Append
}
Write-Host "DistinguishedNames of inactive users printed to $filePath"
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-lastlogontimestamp

Please try this and let me know if it helps.

Comment: It gave the same results :(. I have gone through all the OUs that have users in them and checked the attributes of several users who no longer work here but are still active, and they all have timestamps from 2021 or earlier. None of them are found by this script. Sigh.

Comment: How many domain controllers do you have? The replication may not be consistent so you should test this script on different DCs and see if you get the same results.

Comment: `lastLogonDate` is simply a friendly representation of `lastLogonTimeStamp` and they both share the same 14 day time diff.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thank you for the clarification. So do you think the solution then would be to check across all the DCs? If they are seeing accounts from 2021 then the 14 day time diff doesn't matter right? Is the problem with script or with their AD? Are you aware of any attributes or attribute calculations that can help with this?

Comment: Martin: you can use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75337565/exporting-last-logon-date-for-inactive-users-via-powershell/75339028#75339028 as a reference of how to approach the problem but querying all DCs is the correct way to go. This other answers shows a similar technique in parallel https://stackoverflow.com/a/77085811/15339544 but it would require pwsh 7+

Comment: @Martin Iszac, we only have one DC, so there shouldn't be a replication issue. I tried it on a customer notorious for employee churn and it found nothing, also with just one DC. I can't think of why. It's almost like it won't search all OUs.

Comment: @AdamM can you check again on your accounts permissions and make sure you have the proper rights to query AD, this sounds like a permissions issue at this point.

Comment: @Martin Iszac, I'm running it as the built-in administrator account.

Comment: @AdamM ok lets just try getting results in the console can you try running `Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property samAccountName,lastLogon | Select-Object name,@{n='lastLogon';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogon)}} | Sort-Object lastLogon -Descending` 

What do you get when you run this, it should get all users and sort by last logon. What is the oldest date there.

Answer (score 0):

Running it as administrator got it working right... Thanks @Martin Iszac!